# TLS error occured while trying to connect MQTT client over Secure TLS

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe

Actually, I wanted to implement MQTT SECURE Client over TLS using ESP8266 using Arduino IDE and wanted to check if first working on CMD line or not. But it seems it is NOT WORKING on CMD line itself.

PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF IT IS A BUG or IF ANY CONFIGURATION MISSING. I NEED TO FIX IT AS SOON AS POSSIBLE.

I followed https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html webpage
Generate a certificate authority certificate and key.

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1095 -extensions v3_ca -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt
```

Generate a client key.

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out client.key 2048
```

Generate a certificate signing request to send to the CA.

```
openssl req -out client.csr -key client.key -new
```

Send the CSR to the CA, or sign it with your CA key:

```
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 1095
```

//local.conf file

```
bind_address 127.0.0.1

port 8883

tls_version tlsv1

cafile C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\ca.crt

certfile C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\client.crt

keyfile C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\client.key

require_certificate true
```

// One CMD window

```
mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8883 -q 1 -t sensor/temp --cafile C:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/ca.crt
```

//Second CMD window

```
mosquitto -c local.conf -v
```

I am getting following error:

Error: A TLS error occurred &

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto>mosquitto -c mosquitto_m2mqtt.conf -v
1486436916: mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date 24/08/2016 21:03:24.73) starting

1486436916: Config loaded from mosquitto_m2mqtt.conf.

1486436916: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.

1486436916: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.

Enter PEM pass phrase:

1486436943: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 8883.

1486436943: OpenSSL Error: error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version

1486436943: OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl handshake failure

1486436943: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

Comment: You are using the client certificate/key to identify the server in local.conf not the server certificate/key as described in the document you link to.

Comment: I did not understand. You mean while listening for incoming client, local.conf file we use, should have server cert/key files  that are different from client cert/key files which were used in ESP8266 code ? Both client and server cert/key files created from common ca.crt file ??

Comment: But I am getting same "certificate verify failed" error even though now I am listening on server.crt and server.key files which are generated from  existing ca.crt and ca.key .

Comment: @JyotiRajSharma were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The `require_certificate true` flags means the broker will reject clients the don't supply their own certificate as identify themselves.

Remove this option and your client should connect. If you want to do mutual authentication then you will have to generate a client certificate as well and configure the client to send it along with the connection

Comment: See https://nofurtherquestions.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/making-an-esp8266-web-accessible/ for a description of how to do it with client certificates.

Comment: From ESP8266,I can connect to broker if I just remove "require_certificate true" flag. However, if I enable it, it is giving "routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:certificate verify failed". Please help to fix it, I generated correct "certificates.h" which has client cert and key ( using the link provided by you).  I tried with MQTT.fx 1.0 CLIENT and observed the exact problem (i.e it works as long as require_certificate is false). One more question I have-  "Do not we have to add espClient.loadCertificate(ca) as well ?? ". I think this line is also

Comment: Ask a new question to deal with the ESP8266 Errors, include the src code you are using on the ESP8266. You can include a link to this question for context if needed

Comment: I feel this is not because of ESP8266 because when I tried with MQTT.fx 1.0 CLIENT with ca.crt, client.bin.crt and client.bin.key and observed the exact problem (i.e it works as long as require_certificate is false). It appears to me most likely because of MQTT side. Shall I raise a separate question even though ??